# NSMutableArray with properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, xcode5

i want to setup a NSMutableArray with name, price, reference... as properties.

Like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items;
NSString *name;
NSString *price;
NSString *reference;
```

then add them to the array this way:

```
items[0].name = @"Oven-3000";
items[0].price = @"200€";
items[0].reference = @"231323-1";

items[0].name = @"Oven-3050";
items[0].price = @"250€";
items[0].reference = @"231312-1";

items[0].name = @"Oven-3200";
items[0].price = @"210€";
items[0].reference = @"900023-1";
```

Thx.

Comment: You could create your own object with all properties and add them to array.

Comment: @Norolimba read a book about coding in Objective-C. That's how we all learned. I didn't just get code to copy and paste off stack overflow.

Comment: Generally, you would create NS(Mutable)Dictionary objects (one for each array element) and place your properties in those.  This is very simple to do, once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a special `NSObject` subclass for that.

But if you don't want to do it, you can use `NSDictionary`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:@{@"name": @"Oven-3000",
                   @"price": @"200€",
                   @"reference": @"900023-1"}];

[array addObject:@{@"name": @"Oven-3050",
                   @"price": @"250€",
                   @"reference": @"900023-1"}];

[array addObject:@{@"name": @"Oven-3200",
                   @"price": @"210€",
                   @"reference": @"900023-1"}];
```

Access:

```
array[0][@"name"];
array[0][@"price"];
array[0][@"reference"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the NSObject route, this is how it can be done.

First create a New File from the NSObjectClass and call it something like ItemObject:

[image: new file]

[image: objective-c class]

[image: name the object]

Now in your .H file make the properties (name, price, reference) and add the Method:

[image: properties and method]

In the .M file of the ItemObject class add this method body:

[image: method body]

Your NSObject in now done! To use it in any ViewController add #import "ItemObject" in de .M file:

[image]

To create an object, fill it, add it to array and read it use:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//create objects
ItemObject * item = [[ItemObject alloc]initWithName:@"name1" andPrice:@"price1" andReference:@"reference1"];
ItemObject * item2 = [[ItemObject alloc]initWithName:@"name2" andPrice:@"price2" andReference:@"reference2"];
ItemObject * item3 = [[ItemObject alloc]initWithName:@"name3" andPrice:@"price3" andReference:@"reference3"];

//edit properties
item.name = @"changedTheName";
item.price = @"changedThePrice";
item.reference = @"changedTheReference";

//add to NSMutableArray
NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:item, item2, item3, nil];

//reading from array
ItemObject * itemRetrieved = mutableArray[0]; //first object

//logging content
NSLog(@"itemRetrieved.name:%@",itemRetrieved.name);
}
```

The log will show:

[image: nslog]

Comment: My pleasure! Learned to code on this community, nice to be able to finally give back :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDictionary` to prepare your data like below.

```
NSMutableArray *items=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[items addObject:@{@"name":@"Oven-3000",@"price":@"200€",@"reference":@"231323-1"];
[items addObject:@{@"name":@"Oven-3050",@"price":@"250€",@"reference":@"231312-1"];
[items addObject:@{@"name":@"Oven-3200",@"price":@"210€",@"reference":@"900023-1"];
```

Then fetch

```
for(NSDictionary *dic in items){

   NSLog(@"Name = %@, Price = %@, Reference = %@",[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[dic objectForKey:@"price"],[dic objectForKey:@"reference"])

}
```

**Another way**
As suggest in comments, create your own properties.
Simply create a class of type NSObject, and add properties, and assign.

`MyClass.h`

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *price;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *reference;
@end
```

`MyClass.m`

```
@implementation MyClass
@end
```

Then

```
MyClass *obj=[[MyClass alloc] init];
obj.name=@"Oven-3000";
obj.price=@"200€";
obj.reference=@"900023-1";

[items addObject:obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file name is Product subclass of `NSObject`
in `Product.h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name; //your product name ,arc u use "strong" in place of "retain"
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *price; //product price
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *reference;//product reference


- (id)initWithProductName:(NSString *)Productname productPrice:(NSString *)Productprice withProdctReference:(NSString *)Productreference; //this is the initilizer for your product object
 @end
```

in `Product.m` file

```
 #import "Product.h"

 @implementation Product

@synthesize name;
@synthesize price;
@synthesize reference;

//initilise the product object

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   { //because u dont hav any values for it
     self.name = nil;
     self.price = nil;
     self.reference = nil;
  }
  return  self;
}

//initilise the objec with details
- (id)initWithProductName:(NSString *)Productname productPrice:(NSString *)Productprice withProdctReference:(NSString *)Productreference
{
  self = [super init];
  if(self)
   {
    self.name = Productname;
    self.price = Productprice;
    self.reference = Productreference;
   }
   return self;
}

@end
```

in some other class u need to create object of Product then just `#import "Product.h"`

do like below

```
 NSMutableArray *productItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //to store our products
 Product *product1 = [[Product alloc]initWithProductName:@"Oven-3000" productPrice:@"200€" withProdctReference:@"123213"];
 [productItems addObject:product1];
 Product *product2 = [[Product alloc]initWithProductName:@"Oven-3010" productPrice:@"300€" withProdctReference:@"1231"];
 [productItems addObject:product2];
 Product *product3 = [[Product alloc] initWithProductName:@"" productPrice:@"123€" withProdctReference:@"123123"];
 [productItems addObject:product3];

 //if u want access each items in the array u can do somthing like this
 Product *product = [productItems objectAtIndex:1];
 NSLog(@"name->%@, price->%@, reference->%@",product.name,product.price,product.reference);
```

Comment: down voter can u explain whats is wrong in my answer ... ? does it not match the user requirement ... ?

Comment: Why downvote? Nothings wrong with this answer. I will upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest answer in objective-c way :

```
@interface Item : NSObject
@property NSString *name, *price, *reference;
@end

@implementation Item
- (NSString *)description {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{name: %@, price: %@, reference: %@}", self.name, self.price, self.reference];
}
@end

@interface ItemCollection : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *items;
}
- (Item *)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
- (void)setObject:(Item *)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
@end

@implementation ItemCollection

- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    self->items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (Item *)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx {
  return [self->items objectAtIndexedSubscript:idx];
}

- (void)setObject:(Item *)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx {
  [self->items setObject:obj atIndexedSubscript:idx];
}

- (NSString *)description {
  return [self->items description];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    ItemCollection *items = [[ItemCollection alloc] init];
    items[0] = [[Item alloc] init];
    items[0].name = @"Apple";
    items[0].price = @"$0.99";
    items[0].reference = @"???";

    items[1] = [[Item alloc] init];
    items[1].name = @"Orange";
    items[1].price = @"$0.99";
    items[1].reference = @"AAA";

    NSLog(@"%@", items);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

There are also some other ways, such as *using array of struct* or *using array of pointer*, but I can't make them work in ARC env.